# my code isnt working right but im not sure where the problem is

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("The pile is actually a", (colored("goblin!", "green"), "it jumps at you, ready to fight."))
```

im not exactly sure what to do here, it says that name "colored" is not defined.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions and clean up.

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Main.py", line 49, in <module>
    print("The pile is actually a", (colored("goblin!", "green"), "it jumps at you, ready to fight."))
NameError: name 'colored' is not defined

Comment: @machetazo this is what it was

Comment: @Tacoca: If you have a new question, ask a new question.  Don't overwrite your old question.

Comment: @jwodder i know but it said i couldnt cause my questions werrent "liked enough"

Comment: changed it back now

Answer (score 1):

You need to put yes in quotes.  Your function is receiving a string input, and you are comparing it to an undefined variable yes, instead of a string variable "yes".